# intellij oracle database integration init scripts

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

For oracle databases, I'm interested if intellij (as of idea-15.0.3) database integration has a feature similar sqlplus' auto-running glogin.sql/login.sql/SQLPATH, etc.  Is there a good way in IDEA (or a plugin) to run some initialization scripts every time connecting to an oracle database?